# Show that $\forall x\in U: dF_x=\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x)e_j^*$

Tags: real-analysis

I am going through some practice questions in preparation for an exam on real analysis and I haven't got a clue on how to answer this one. Thanks in advance to anyone that can solve this or tell me the steps to solving it.

Let $U \subset\mathbb{R}^n $ be open and $F:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ differentiable. Show that:
$$\forall x\in U: dF_x=\sum^n_{j=1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x)e_j^*    $$ where $(e_1^*, ...,e_n^*)$ is the standard basis of the vectorspace $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ of linear forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, meaning the dual basis to the basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $e_j^*(e_i)=\delta_{ij}$

Comment: you wrote $\delta F / \delta x_j$ , do you mean $\partial F / \partial x_j$? Also, what is your definition of $dF_x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $dF_x$ I assume you mean the Frechet derivative of $F$ at $x\in U$. The key thing you need to establish is that for every $j \in \{1, \dots, n\},$ $dF_x(e_j) = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x)$; after that it's just basic linear algebra.

Assuming this for now, we can say that for every $\xi = (\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n)\in \Bbb{R}^n$, 
\begin{align}
dF_x(\xi) &= dF_x \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j e_j \right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n dF_x(e_j) \cdot \xi_j \tag{$dF_x$ is linear} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x) \cdot (e_j)^*(\xi) \tag{definition of dual basis} \\
&= \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x) (e_j)^* \right)(\xi)
\end{align}

Hence, if we do not mention the argument $\xi$ explicitly, we get that
\begin{align}
dF_x = \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x) (e_j)^*
\end{align}

---

Now, we'll prove that $dF_x(e_j) = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x)$. But actually, we can prove slightly more with not much more effort. Let $v\in \Bbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary, and define $\gamma_v: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^n$ by $\gamma_v(t) = x + tv$. Then,
\begin{align}
(F \circ \gamma_v)'(0) &= dF_{\gamma_v(0)}(\gamma_v'(0)) \tag{chain rule} \\
&= dF_{x}(v) 
\end{align}

If you replace $v$ with $e_j$ above, then the LHS $(F \circ \gamma_{e_j})'(0)$ is exactly the partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(x)$ (write out the limit of the difference quotice of $(F \circ \gamma_{e_j})'(0)$ to convince yourself).

Comment: Thank you, this is very understandable!